# vaadin eclipse plugin installation

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

My Environment:
OS: Windows XP
Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.5.1
Build id: M20090917-0800

I am new to Vaadin. Trying to install the Vaadin Plugin for Eclipse. I opted for offline installation. Downloaded the JARS bundle from http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-plug-in-for-eclipse.

Earlier I was getting the error as follows:

> Cannot connect to keystore. This trust engine is read only. Cannot
>   complete the install because one or more required items could not be
>   found. Software currently installed: Vaadin Visual Designer for
>   Eclipse (upgrade only) 2.0.1.201105170102
>   (com.vaadin.wysiwyg.eclipse.feature.group 2.0.1.201105170102) Missing
>   requirement: Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 2.0.1.201105170102
>   (com.vaadin.integration.eclipse 2.0.1.201105170102) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found Cannot
>   satisfy dependency: From: Vaadin Visual Designer for Eclipse (upgrade
>   only) 2.0.1.201105170102 (com.vaadin.wysiwyg.eclipse.feature.group
>   2.0.1.201105170102) To: com.vaadin.integration.eclipse 2.0.0

Then I downloaded the Mylyn from www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/.

Still getting the error:

> Cannot connect to keystore. This trust engine is read only. Cannot
>   complete the install because one or more required items could not be
>   found. Software currently installed: Vaadin Visual Designer for
>   Eclipse (upgrade only) 2.0.1.201105170102
>   (com.vaadin.wysiwyg.eclipse.feature.group 2.0.1.201105170102) Missing
>   requirement: Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 2.0.1.201105170102
>   (com.vaadin.integration.eclipse 2.0.1.201105170102) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found Cannot
>   satisfy dependency: From: Vaadin Visual Designer for Eclipse (upgrade
>   only) 2.0.1.201105170102 (com.vaadin.wysiwyg.eclipse.feature.group
>   2.0.1.201105170102) To: com.vaadin.integration.eclipse 2.0.0

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to install it from the update site?

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to install online from [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/eclipse)

You will get instructions there and plus, you can choose to get the book, API and demo

Answer (score 3):

I had the same mistake.

You have this error because there is a missing dependency in eclipse. There is two solution.

A. Install the **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** version from eclipse download site http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and then install the

B. Keep your current version of Eclipse and install the missing module: Mylyn Common.

Sorry I tried to post the image but stackoverflow dont allow it.

---

Answer (score -1):

Simple. Just visit their site and you'll get all the instructions you need. it's http://vaadin.com/eclipse and I'm sure you'll be just fine